# Creating a control IN FRONT of an OpenGL view

Tags: macos, opengl, nstextfield

I have an OpenGL view on the Mac. I want to put a NSTextField in front of it, but even if I put it in front, it is obscured by the view.

There is a very simple test case. Create a new project in XCode (I'm using 4.0.2) and a window. Add an OpenGL view. Now add a text field and set it so that half of it overlaps the OpenGL view. Run the program. The whole field shows, but when you type the text, only half of it shows, no matter how you arrange the fields front to back.

Answer (score 2):

An `NSOpenGLView` doesn't actually draw within the window, it draws in a surface that is above or below the window, above by default.  If you want a control in front of the OpenGL surface, you must make the surface below the window, using the `NSOpenGLContext` parameter `NSOpenGLCPSurfaceOrder`.  But then you must cut a transparent rectangle in the window to be able to see the OpenGL surface.

Edit to add:  Alternately, you could make a transparent overlay or child window that is above the OpenGL surface as well as the main window, and put the control there.  Not sure which way would be easier.

Comment: I took your suggestion and tried several other things. I changed the NSOpenGLCPSurfaceOrder parameter to -1 and I could now see the field, but not the OpenGL image. I changed the window to be transparent, but the OpenGL field remained white. I'm not sure how to make the OpenGL view white -- I don't see any calls in NSView to do this.

Comment: I created a new window with a NSTextField in it and made the above window's background transparent (more on that later). That sorta worked, but it makes mouse clicks sorta interesting, because I'll have to catch them in one window, and then pass them on to the next window. There is code at Apple that shows how to do that, but the project "FunkyOverlayWindow" depends on OS X 10.7, and I need this to work on OS 10.5. I'll take a look further and see if there is code that I can extract to make that happen.

Comment: By the way, the code to make a window's background transparent is  NSColor *backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.0 
               green:0.0 
                blue:0.0
               alpha:0.0];
 [_overlayWindow setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
 [_overlayWindow setAlphaValue:.9999];
Note that the "setAlphaValue" value MUST be .9999. If it is 1.0, then you have a black window. Go figure.